# Remove ISP toolbar from http://ets-amsg-ins-xl.mobixell.com/ets/scripts/Anchor.js

Tags: javascript, toolbar

this is gone too far now everytime I connect to internet, an annoying picture appears on the left bottom of the page. I looked at the pagesource and found this
http://ets-amsg-ins-xl.mobixell.com/ets/scripts/Anchor.js

how can i block this from the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can't block this from browser. But, you can block it from your OS hosts list instead.

For Windows 8 Users, please go to :

C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc

Edit "hosts" with Administrator permission or with current user with granted permission (Right click on file -> Properties -> Security -> Set your account )

Then add this line:

127.0.0.1 ets-amsg-ins-xl.mobixell.com

For Linux users,

Usually it's located in /etc/hosts.

Simply as put :

127.0.0.1 ets-amsg-ins-xl.mobixell.com

Now the slow internet connection issue should gone forever.